# Android: private variable scope in a class

Tags: java, android

```
Requirement: I want passWord to be accessible everywhere in the class.
```

This is the code:

```
public class DetailComm extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String passWord;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private Button mSendButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        final Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(<mylink>).orderByKey().equalTo(<myname>);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {

                for (final DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    passWord = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                    //Point 1. Toast prints correct value of passWord here//
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });
        if (bundle != null) {
            for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                Toast.makeText(DetailComm.this, passWord.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Point 2. Toast prints blank output here//
            }
        }

        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Point 3. Toast displays correct value of passWord here!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The question is: how can the same variable be inaccessible at Point 2 here? If at point 1 when I set passWord, it is in a different class, it might explain point 2 having null string, but then, should it also not be inaccessible at point3? What am I missing?

How can I make passWord accessible everywhere in the class? I changed it to a public variable, Point 2 still displays null value. Also, this class is one of the many classes in the project. I know for sure there is no other class with this variable name.

Comment: You issue seems to be a race condition. You set the value of `passWord`  when firebase is done fetching the data. However the code at point 2 is run immediatly after asking firebase to get the data and leave it no time to actually do the job. So when you are at point 2 `passWord` is simply not loaded yet. Point 3 is triggered by a click so firebase have time to load the data before you have time to actually click the button. You can easilly verify this by putting some breakpoints and checking in which order they hit

Comment: @litelite edited code to remove confusion.

Comment: @litelite yup, logcat timestamp shows me point 2 is hit before point 1. Should have been the first thing i should have looked at. My bad. To implement the functionality of my code, I am thinking of having firebase query, checking if passWord is not null, then calling a new intent to another class which will have the rest of the code above. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set value in the Listener anonymous class which means that variable initialize only when event is happenned, in your case, when data change in FireBase db or when the first-time response was delivered. 
But point 2 happens exactly after you set the Listener, so it happens BEFORE point 1. That's why you give the null value.
And, in addition, point 3 also happens in lustener, so it very unclear which of points will be called first - point 1 or point 3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Same qn as in the comment above:To implement the functionality of my code, I am thinking of having firebase query, checking if passWord is not null, then calling a new intent to another class which will have the rest of the code above. Is this the only way?

Comment: @seriouslyfunny You can disable button in xml, and enable it in code again when l query has been completed (at the end of onDataChange()